# form posting arabic as "Ø³ÙØ¨ÃÂ§Ã"

Tags: php, html

i was working on a multilingual project and doing ok ... and when testing found that arabic input will be changed into "Ø³ÙØ¨ÃÂ§Ã" once posted with forms .
its not a database problem cuz as soon as i print($_POST) without processing the data in any way it shows that output meaining it hasn't reached that query yet

i have tried the following yet :

1 -

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8") or die('couldnt modify character set: ' . $mysqli->error);
```

2 -

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8") or die();
```

3 -

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

```
<pre><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa"></pre>
<pre><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></pre>
```

and i havent done anything special except its the first time ive used the views (includes)

Comment: Was the mysql table set to UTF8?

Comment: yup all the fields and tables and the db are given a collation of "utf-8 general ci"

Comment: Please show a sample codes , the above posted codes are well.

Comment: use <meta charset="utf-8" /> in your form page